# Can frozen egg whites be used in a macaron recipe?

Tags: baking, freezing, egg-whites, macarons

I put a few egg whites in the freezer a few couple months ago (frozen in an ice cube tray, then transferred to a freezer bag).  Would they be viable for using in a macaron recipe (either French or Italian)?  Or do I really need fresh ones that have been aged?

I've seen a few sources that claim it will probably work fine, while another source claims they will be too watery to work (for a French recipe, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but the results may not be the best, when it comes to tenderness and aeration of the finished (baked) product. Coagulated egg products are mainly used for omelettes, scrambled eggs and souffles especially for mass production, or great quantities.

In cooking, but especially in confectionery making, fresh eggs are usually used, especially for preparations that are very delicate, like macarons.

Comment: Given that I'm just getting started at macaron making, I was afraid it would be a point of failure rather than affecting the texture.  Since I didn't want to risk wasting the almonds, I used the defrosted whites in meringue cookies.  They turned out OK, but since I've never had one before, I don't know if that's what they're supposed to taste like.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use them for - creams, meringues, meringues and even pasta with.freezing Method tested by me for a long time, never failed. Well whipped, just recently used frozen whites when baking a sponge cake. 
I tried all possible options and came to the conclusion that it is enough a day before cooking to separate the proteins from the yolks and leave the proteins on the kitchen table, covered with a film in which to make a few cuts with a knife. The second option, which also came to me: hold the whites in the fridge for 2-3 days and 3-4 hours prior to cooking remove from refrigerator. It's enough for the proteins to reach room temperature.